# Where do CVs have a smaller weight

Tags: resume

What professions and industries put less focus into the CV and more into the present offer?

I know that the corporate world will more 'CV-oriented' and check any 'blemishes' than start-ups. Equally self-employed are analyzed less in terms of CVs than job-seekers.

However, what further advice to find a more liberal environment, where you can work without worrying too much about social stigma.

My target here is find a field where I would fit well, despite being out of the work-force due to a (already dealt with) medical issue and having a broken college record (a mixture of good and bad grades, dropping off but coming back).

Comment: So you aren't qualified to do anything, but you want to know what profession would would hire you anyway because you are just such a great person? You do understand that you are in competition with others for jobs right? Others who have gotten qualified for the jobs they seek?

Comment: Can you explain what field of work you're hoping to work in?

Answer (score 2):

Artistic work - photographers, illustrators - introduce themselves with a portfolio of samples. Your 'blemishes', whatever those might be, won't show up.

Obviously, the past here is never indifferent, and if you have worked with whoever is the reference in the field, you are better off than the rest.

Another option are  services that can be measured. For example, a moving company that transports x boxes across the country for y bucks.  In this case you can compete on price.

Add to the self-employed, an LLC. It's not as if people would automatically trust a company, but normally they won't ask for a CV of the people inside when the company is offering a service.

Subtract all the services where you have to trust the provider, like consulting.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is the harder it is to find staff, the fewer issues are raised about things like medical history or grades.  One area I see a lot of 'no questions asked' work is Internet Service Provider tech support - these don't pay much but work is needed 24/7 for, technically, millions of users.  This would 'get you a job', although not much of one.

Startups may not pay any attention to your CV, but that employment interview is going to be a lot tougher - it will be face to face and if you don't understand what they're doing you're out.  Big companies might want a clean record as far as finance and criminal history, but often they tolerate 'middle grade' skills precisely because such people are less likely to quit for better opportunities, and they are more likely to put up with corporate horse(baloney).  However, lots of people want the 'corporate bennies', so you're competing in a crowded field.

People ask fewer questions about contractors since they can be let go the instant any performance issue arises.  Such workers generally find more to do with smaller companies, and the local medical clinic people may not even know what kinds of questions to ask - they just try to figure out whether you can help.  As long as that answer is 'yes' they keep you around.